# How to show result with Int on calculator?

Tags: java, android, calculator

I am making the calculator app. It shows double at the result even when I don't use double.
Example) 1+1 = 2.0

But I want like 1+1= 2

Of course, I want to keep double when there is double like 1.2+1.3= 2.5

How should I have to edit?

I tried to edit like this, but there is an error.

```
public void equalsOnClick(View view)
{
    Integer result = null;
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("rhino");

    try {
        result = (int)engine.eval(workings);
    } catch (ScriptException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if(result != null)
        resultsTV.setText(String.valueOf(result.intValue()));

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView workingsTV;
    TextView resultsTV;

    String workings = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initTextView();
    }

    private void initTextView()
    {
        workingsTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.workingsTextView);
        resultsTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
    }

    private void setWorkings(String givenValue)
    {
        workings = workings + givenValue;
        workingsTV.setText(workings);
    }

    public void equalsOnClick(View view)
    {
        Double result = null;
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("rhino");

        try {
            result = (double)engine.eval(workings);
        } catch (ScriptException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if(result != null)
            resultsTV.setText(String.valueOf(result.doubleValue()));
    }

    public void clearOnClick(View view)
    {
        workingsTV.setText("");
        workings = "";
        resultsTV.setText("");
        leftBracket = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the DecimalFormat class to determine how a double is formatted. You can display it as 2, or as 2.0 or even more decimal places if needed.

Comment: @LiveandLetLive thank you for spending your time to help me. I am really a beginner that I got the above code from youtube. I am trying to understand the code you write. Thank you so much to share your knowledge!!!! I do appreciate it so much!!!

Comment: You are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because you have declared `result` of type, `Double`. Therefore, until you cast it's `doubleValue()` into an `int` and set the same to `resultsTV`, its `double` value will be set there.

Change your method definition as follows:

```
public void equalsOnClick(View view) {
    Double result = null;
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("rhino");

    try {
        result = (Double)engine.eval(workings);
        if(result != null) {
            int intVal = (int)result.doubleValue();
            if(result == intVal) {// Check if it's value is equal to its integer part
                resultsTV.setText(String.valueOf(intVal));
            } else {
                resultsTV.setText(String.valueOf(result));
            }
        }
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }    
}
```

Note that I have also moved `resultsTV.setText` inside the `try-catch` block so that it gets executed only when `result = (Double)engine.eval(workings)` does not throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulo operator to check whether a double is an Integer
(result %1 ==0)
or Math.floor then check whether result changed or not.

If it is, you can use Integer.valueOf(result)

Integer has a built in toString method by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do.

Just check the string on whether it ended with `".0"`
If so, just replace the string like this: `replace(".0","");`

In the else condition, insert the string as you input like now.